# Just had 170 points removed. Excessive?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It is claimed that when a user is removed points will not be taken away when that would result in in an excessive loss of reputation. What is excessive? -170 points is more reputation than most people have total on this site. What does it take, -10000 before it is excessive? I have never earned +170 points in a single day.

**Question 1**  What is excessive?

Note please, that this is unusual enough that it seems problematic. Either someone was very negatively treated, or had a negative reaction to something and withdrew voluntarily. Either case suggests a problem with the site. I have lately gotten a rather negative impression from some actions taken by this site, can we somehow accentuate the positive a bit more, please?

Next, between downvoting mistakenly, incorrect remarks, *ad hominem* argument, bizarre administrative posturing, e.g., ineffectually coercing pathetic niceties.  The quality and 'niceness' itself of the experience on this site could stand improvement.

**Question 2**  Can something be done to improve user experience,  i.e.,  less negative?

Comment: I got -375 today. This is how the site works. This is not specific to CV, but all the SE ecosystem. See for further discussion and links: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it

Comment: I got -645 today, 635 of that from one user...

Comment: Someone fooled SE for a long time;  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night; https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/user-was-removed-with-significant-amount-of-votes-withdrawn-was-it-a-fraud. More about “user was removed” in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted.

Comment: Please do not take it personally Carl it has happened to all of us today and many people (including me) lost much more than you.

Comment: @mdewey Wrong impression. I do not take it personally. It is just that removal of excessive reputation is not supposed to happen, and -635 like  Glen_b reports, seems excessive, and no corrective action was undertaken, which detracts from a wholesome site experience.

Comment: @Nick_Craver Note this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173699/341152 What about it Nick?  Can this type of thing be stopped?

Comment: Q1 is very reasonable and very suitable for the Meta; I would happily upvote it. However, Q2 is almost unrelated and is formulated in a way that makes me want to downvote. Consider separating this question into two distinct ones.

Comment: @amoeba Please explain. I cannot guess as to why you feel that way. Also, please consider that not everyone's  experiences are carbon copies of each other's.

Comment: "snarky downvoting, snide remarks, personal deprecation, a punitive administrative approach to users" In abstraction, no one is favour of any of these, but each accusation requires context and evidence. To start with the most discussed, who decides which downvotes are snarky? Most of them are silent, so you are imputing intent. Professionally we (should) know that imputation is very tricky! Most positively, to fight back against anything untoward you need (a) moderators on your side (b) other active users in support to vote, comment, flag, edit, etc.

Comment: By far the most difficult person in my time on CV  (a long, long way from you, @Carl)  complained again and again about behaviour of which they were the most notorious exemplar.....

Comment: @NickCox Understood. However, any discussion of anything involves projection whether from the ontogenetic  dichotomy of subjective versus objective or the [holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle). In simplest terms, we do not experience reality, we experience personal models of it. And if our models do not agree, how common those models are, how democratic, contributes nothing objective.

Comment: I don't know how to decode that easily except as a reminder of the obvious. I doubt that anyone accepts that A is to be thought snarky (or whatever) just because B says they are. You have to convince the community or their elected moderators for anything to happen. They have to agree that A is snarky (and, very often, consider whether B is behaving as badly or worse).

Comment: @NickCox A scientist is someone who tests the veracity of dogma. Most do not, and science is not popular. Surely a lack of popularity is not scientific evidence but neither is dogma. Do I have to establish the obvious just because it is not obvious to everyone? Take downvoting. Two propositions 1) There are no problems with it.  2) There are problems with  it. Which proposition is scientific?

Comment: @NickCox Regarding proposition 1; the popular consensus that is, there are numerous threads on StackExchange meta complaining about downvoting, and the consensus votes against those numerous threads, complaints have been posted about the high frequency of said posts, which speaks volumes about how many people do have a problem with downvoting. Fine, we can agree that it is a minority opinion ruthlessly discounted by its proponents, but, the criticism of downvoting will persist unless the deficiencies are better addressed.

Comment: Sure, downvoting can be abused. Some downvotes are in bad faith. Who is arguing otherwise? Some people have done or said some things to me on SE that I didn't like, but I didn't start any Meta threads on any of them. That's a repeated, invisible zero from anyone who thinks similarly. So, it's really, really hard, but you have to impute the number of those satisfied enough with the system to stay, and not complain much. I can't regard my views as "ruthless".  I don't have any scope to be ruthless here.

Comment: @NickCox No, no. You are good-natured. Some of the anti-anti-downvoting comments surely are not nice. However, I am not impugning motive here, rather methods. That is, the problem is that what people think is true, often is irreal. Problematic downvoting  occurs for true but unfamiliar statements. Uncommon truths are not easily digested, in fact if something new does not make someone uncomfortable, it probably was not worth saying.

Comment: Happy to have misunderstood then, but as before only so much can be said in abstraction. If I see specific cases, I can work out how far I agree.

Comment: @NickCox I have taken out the emotional attribution that some have objected to as not properly communicating the objective character of my experience. There is also a subjective component to this, which is not invalid, just irrelevant to the point I am trying to convey. Perhaps that will help people understand.

Comment: @amoeba OK, changed wording, I do not care about downvoting. I assume that anything worth saying will be downvoted. Indeed, that is why I consider downvoting problematic.

Comment: I appreciate the intent but changing your wording to "downvoting mistakenly, incorrect remarks, ad hominem argument, bizarre administrative posturing, e.g., ineffectually coercing pathetic niceties" just seems like tinkering. I prefer vivid language to bland truisms, with nothing else said, but I still don't think Question 2 is a good question for Meta. It assumes too much and is based on so little that we can see, however much personal experience underlies it. Still, it's particularly pertinent to flag that I didn't downvote this. (As of this writing,  +3 -2 = 1 vote for this question.)

Comment: @NickCox Why? My thought is that losing a bunch of points through no fault of the recipient due to user removal is a negative experience, which more generally is part and parcel of the other causes of negative experiences, the likes of which might just be worthy of some consideration.

Comment: Again: for anyone to decide which downvotes were undeserved requires a view from above of who was right, who was wrong, and whether the reasons for downvoting were good or bad. No one has this view from Olympus. Anyone thin-skinned enough to react badly to how the votes fall should find a different home or hobby. (I recommended to the person alluded to several comments above that they start their own blog. Characteristically they didn't seem interested in anyone else's advice.)

Comment: @NickCox Einstein characteristically did not care much for the people in his department who so disliked his theories that they disliked him, which is why he wrote relativity while employed in the Swiss Patent Office. To this day there are people who are in love with disliking Einstein. There is more to this than Mount Olympus. Deep thought will never be popular, and voting is a popularity contest. Thinking about it is not heresy and if we could develop better methods it would be very rewarding for all concerned.

Comment: I guess we could lobby for downvotes received to be explicit in each person's profile if they are seen as badges of honour. As a statistical person I have to comment that for every maverick who turns out to be Einstein there are many more who turn out to be just mavericks.

Comment: @NickCox For every maverick who is not ignored when correct there are ten who are ignored when correct. Works both ways.

Comment: That's one assertion each without supporting evidence. I think I'll let readers decide for themselves.

Comment: @NickCox Aye! There is the rub. Letting readers decide without evidence. I rather thought that was the problem, not the solution to it.

Comment: -1 Specifically for "down-voting mistakenly, incorrect remarks" which seems deeply problematic, paternalistic, and colonizing. I would give a second down-vote for "bizarre administrative posturing, e.g., ineffectually coercing pathetic niceties," since (here and on other SEs) creating a welcoming and friendly environment creates opportunities for people to learn in both asking questions & answering them, fosters sharing of differing perspectives, and reduces bullying behavior.

Comment: @Alexis Are words like 'paternalistic' and 'colonizing,' whatever the heck that means, nice words to use toward a respected colleague? Or, do they signal a lack of respect and proper comportment? It is all too typical to overreact negatively on this site and that, for me if not for you, constitutes a barrier to proper discussion that mitigates against creative thought. I have had to delete some very good ideas because of that and from my perspective the site is not optimal. I do sincerely hope that your experiences have been more positive.

Comment: Carl, I appreciate your presence on the site and have said so before.

Comment: @Alexis Thank-you, one compliment is worth 10 less than flattering remarks. The expression of causes for concern is only in an effort to improve the site. I have seen a statement (to someone else, I think) to the effect that if someone wants a better site, they should start their own. And I have also heard that to learn to write a good book, one should read a bad one. It is my experience that one gets published by following reviewers' guidance. And so should this site.

Comment: @amoebasaysReinstateMonica Please allow me to remind you of Question 2. Do you still want to downvote it, or do you concede that there is an administrative attitude problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A lot of people across the SE network have noticed the same thing: see [Massive user removal in one night?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328642/225179) & [Please update the text in help for "User was Removed" reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328672/225179).

In fine, when a user deletes their account, whether or not to reverse the votes they've cast is decided by SE staff if the vote count exceeds a certain threshold.

> Note that we will not define the exact thresholds for how many votes will trigger review.

Reasons for not preserving votes include, but are not limited to, vote fraud.

Comment: OK (+1) Mind explaining the difference between fraudulent voting and incomprehensible voting from miscomprehension? I realize you do not own the opinion you have expressed, but, I also wonder what fraud could possibly mean in this context.

Comment: @Carl: Fraudulent voting's when a single person controls multiple accounts that vote for each other.

Comment: Thanks, that possibility never occurred to me. Since voting is next to worthless as far as I can tell, it did not occur to me that anyone would bother doing such a thing.